# JQ filtered data with included parent key

Tags: jq

I have json with given content:

[elements.json](https://pastebin.com/sb7fxszP)

```
{
  "Metals": {
    "AlkaliMetals": {
      "Lithium": {
        "MeltingPoint": "453",
        "BoilingPoint": "1615"
      },
      "Sodium": {
        "MeltingPoint": "371",
        "BoilingPoint": "1156"
      }
    },
    "AlkalineEarthMetals": {
      "Beryllium": {
        "MeltingPoint": "1560",
        "BoilingPoint": "2743"
      },
      "Magnesium": {
        "MeltingPoint": "923",
        "BoilingPoint": "1363"
      }
    }
  },
  "Metalloids": {
    "Metaloids": {
      "Boron": {
        "MeltingPoint": "2348",
        "BoilingPoint": "4273"
      },
      "Silicon": {
        "MeltingPoint": "1687",
        "BoilingPoint": "3173"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

currently I generate output with this command:

```
jq -r -S '.[][] | keys[] as $k | "\($k):\(.[$k] | .MeltingPoint):\(.[$k] | .BoilingPoint)"' elements.json
```

whitch gives me:

```
Lithium:453:1615 ...
```

I would like to have this extended to have also parent key:

```
AlkaliMetals:Lithium:453:1615 ...
```

or all keys:

```
Metals:AlkaliMetals:Lithium:453:1615 ...
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the JSON document that you show:

```
$ jq -r 'path(.[][][]) as $p | "\($p|join(":")):\(getpath($p).MeltingPoint):\(getpath($p).BoilingPoint)"' file.json
Metals:AlkaliMetals:Lithium:453:1615
Metals:AlkaliMetals:Sodium:371:1156
Metals:AlkalineEarthMetals:Beryllium:1560:2743
Metals:AlkalineEarthMetals:Magnesium:923:1363
Metalloids:Metaloids:Boron:2348:4273
Metalloids:Metaloids:Silicon:1687:3173
```

This iterates over the "paths" of all objects at level 3 of the document (i.e. the paths to the `Lithium`, `Sodium`, etc. structures) as `$p`.  Each `$p` is an array like `["Metals","AlkaliMetals","Sodium"]`. It uses the current path to create the initial part of each output line by joining up the path with `:` as delimiters.  The actual boiling and melting temperatures are fetched using `getpath()` from the current path and the values are appended to the end of the string.

This seems to also work on the lager file that you link to, but outputs `null` for temperature data that is missing.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Null values for larger file are expected